# Copying distance matrix as a matrix into excel from R

Tags: r, excel, matrix

I have a column in a dataframe (x) for which I want to find pairwise distance between all the entries using the `dist(x$columnname)` function. The output is a distance matrix, but if I use the `writeClipboard` function to copy the data into excel I get a list of all pairwise distances. Is there a way I can copy it into excel keeping the matrix format intact ?

Comment: Not sure to understand. Try to copy the matrix and run `read.table(file="clipboard")` in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For copying data from R to Excel I wrote this little function, which you can use:

```
    writeClipboardDf <- function (dat, format = 1, colnames = TRUE, rownames = FALSE, 
                              token = "\t") {
    if (is.null(dim(dat))) {
       writeClipboard(as.character(dat), format)
    }
    else {
       strDf <- apply(dat, 1, paste, collapse = token)
       if (rownames) {
          rn <- rownames(dat)
          if (is.null(rn)) {
             rn <- 1:(nrow(dat))
          }
          if (colnames) {
             strDf <- c(paste(names(dat), collapse = token), 
                        strDf)
             rn <- c("", rn)
          }
          strDf <- paste(rn, strDf, sep = token)
       }
       else {
          if (colnames) {
             strDf <- c(paste(names(dat), collapse = token), 
                        strDf)
          }
       }
       writeClipboard(strDf, format)
    }
}
```

Basically, it takes the input and adds tabs `\t` such taht you can conveniently paste the data into Excel. All you have to do then is to call `writeClipboardDf(as.matrix(dist(x$columnname)))`.

Answer (score 7):

Try to convert the matrix to a data frame and then write it to a csv file.

```
mydf<-as.data.frame(as.matrix(dist_matrix_name))
write.csv(mydf,file = "filename.csv")
```

Comment: I did try that. It says cannot coerce class ""dist"" to a data.frame

Comment: did you try `as.data.frame(as.matrix())`?